# Switching 1875 Volts through a relay

Tags: relay, high-voltage, low-power, electrostatic

I am trying to create an electroadhesive device that I can switch on and off easily, however, after using one relay that worked beautifully to do this function, I went out and bought a 4 channel relay module, and with this module, switching does not seem to work. I can still hear the relay switch when I send it 5 volts through my arduino uno and there is an LED on the module that lights up, signifying a switch, but the attached adhesive barely adheres to anything. With my original relay, I had to wrestle with the adhesives to pull them apart.

Something interesting I noticed after hooking up high voltage is the LED indicator that typically signifies a switched relay is on, but very dim. Without the high voltage, this LED is completely off. I don't see any arcing, but I think I hear a very quiet and constant clicking, like a car engine cooling off after shutting it down.

**Things I have tried so far...**

- The 4M Ohm is four 1M Ohm resistors in series, so I moved the lead
  going into the relay down one resistor. I am not sure, but I think the LED to signify relay activation slightly dimmed?
- I would love to try and replace the relay on the relay module with the one I know that works, but while I do have a soldering iron, I don't have any experience or the tools to remove components. I started poking at some pins on the fourth relay with my iron while tugging on it a little bit from the other side, but to no avail.

**4 Channel Relay Module** Velleman 4 Chanel Relay Module
https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/29/vma400_a4v01.pdf

**Original relay that worked** Goodsky RW-SH-103D
https://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/7532264449810669947

**High Voltage DC-DC Booster** XP Power Emco G25
https://www.xppower.com/Portals/0/pdfs/SF_G_Series.pdf

For the 4 channel relay module, I am powering it off of the 5V from the arduino.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdQqxE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
I am aware that the original relay only needs 3 volts to actuate. Lacking a lot of equipment like proper power supplies so I am just using wall adapters for power right now.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice! This is my first post here and I am a Mechatronics student still in school so don't hold back on criticism!

Comment: Relays have a voltage rating. 1875V is way above the voltage of a regular relay. If it ever worked at all, it won't work for long. Not to mention it's not safe since the relay was never made to isolate such a high voltage. You need to get a relay rated for at least 1875V and then you will need to find a small transistor so the CPU can drive the transistor which can drive the relay. This was taken cared of on your relay board, but a 1875V relay isn't going to be packaged like that.

Comment: Do you have any alternatives in mind to switch something like this? I need to have this on top of thick foam padding on somebody's forearm...

Comment: How much current do you need?

Comment: Extremely little. My DC-DC booster only outputs a max of 0.60 mA.

Comment: How much capacitance does it have, this is the energy stored

Comment: Consider a suitable IGBT

Comment: Maybe these:
https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Coto-Technology/5501-05-1?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsqIr59i2oRcvK4qULNrA1UpAIQjct04LI%3D
or
https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Coto-Technology/5501-12-1?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsqIr59i2oRcuiHt50Ib0TCmzIrtiCvSIc%3D

But right now this does not sound safe to be wearing on your person. I've seen things that were AT MOST (i.e. they were probably lower) 1200V arc across air gaps a few mm through anodized barriers that were normally insultating.

Comment: If you are talking about the capacitance for the electroadhesives, I am not entirely sure myself. I am using the formula found on page four of this paper.
https://ait.ethz.ch/projects/2018/dextres/downloads/dextrES.pdf
I was using permittivity of urethane. I am currently using packing tape as the dielectric film though. Area is 6 inches squared, with the distance, also being fairly unknown, but if I had to guess, 13 micrometers.

Comment: Solid-state relays like [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electric-works/AQV258A/255-1558-5-ND/570696) may be the most cost-effective way to get what you need done. Ones rated for such high voltages are rare, but cheaper than similarly rated electromechanical relays.

Comment: Rather than use a relay, simply switch the power to your DC-DC converter on/off. The 4M Ohm resistor will collapse the output.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to control three electroadhesives. If I were to turn on and off the DC-DC converter, then the adhesives themselves could only be on or off as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheets show

[image]

- The Velleman relay is rated for 30 V DC switching.
- The Goodsky relay is rated for 110 V DC switching.

Neither is rated for 1875 V DC.

The Goodsky is the less worse of the two. If you open the Velleman relays you should find the contacts welded or burn out.

The other problem you are ignoring is that the breakdown voltage between the contacts and the coil may be considerably less than 1875 V and so you risk flashover from the high voltage into your low voltage control circuit.

Comment: Ahh, ok. so if I were to switch out the relays, then I should be in a better position than I was before? Or is there potentially something else at fault with the 4 channel relay module I bought?

Comment: Your comment suggests that you don't understand that the relays were ***way*** under-rated for the task. You need to use relays with adequate DC voltage and current ratings. You may be able to use a Velleman module to switch the high-voltage relays.

Comment: I was aware that these relays were definitively not rated for this task, but I was desperate at the time and looking for solutions. I have never touched relays in school up until this point, so this was a learning experience for me. I was under the impression that maybe the contacts were spaced far enough to avoid arcing during non actuation since it is an electromechanical device.

Comment: The problem will be during contact opening. An arc will form and eat away at the contacts while they are opening. The next problem will be that the gap between the contacts might not be enough - even when new - to force the arc to extinguish. As mentioned, the contacts and coil are crammed into a tiny container so there isn't much of a gap between the contacts and coil so the voltage may jump the gap.

Comment: I don't understand how you are "desperate" or unwilling to follow equpment specifications when dealing with medical equipment.  No reputable medical supplier would build such a thing even at prototype.  Is this for BDSM or some other sort of hobby deal?